# Aggregate function after having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, database-schema

Considering that we have the following schema:

```
Emp(eid:integer, ename:string, age:integer, salary:real)
Works(eid:integer, did:integer, pct_time:integer)
Dept(did:integer, budget:real, managerid:integer)
```

The question asks "If a manager manages more than one department, he or she controls the sum of all the budgets for those departments. Find the managerids of managers who control more than $5 million." I wrote the following queries for this problem:

Version 1:

```
SELECT d.managerid 
FROM   department d 
GROUP  BY managerid 
HAVING (SELECT Sum(d2.budget) 
        FROM   department d2 
        WHERE  d.managerid = d2.managerid) > 5000000
```

Version 2:

```
SELECT   d.managerid
FROM     department d 
GROUP BY managerid 
HAVING   Sum(d.budget) > 5000000
```

I would like to know what is the difference between the above 2 queries? Is the nested SELECT statement required for having clause?

Edit: Is version 1 redundant since the **GROUP BY** keyword allows the sum function to return the sum of the department budgets for each manager?

Comment: Version 1 is redundant.  Version 2 seems to answer the question.

Comment: But If I use the WHERE keyword I have to do nested select? like WHERE(SELECT Sum(d2.budget) 
        FROM   department d2 
        WHERE  d.managerid = d2.managerid) > 5000000

Comment: That sounds like another question.  You should ask a question as a question, with sample data and desired results.